# Using Firebase with Parse in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, firebase

I have been looking at using Firebase to implement a chat feature into my application - However I am struggling to find solid tutorials on how to do so..

I have found some resources on the Firebase site that links to a git with an example of an application - but I still struggle a little with reading and dissecting other peoples code and would benefit more from following a tutorial that can explain the concepts a little more in-depth.

Does anyone know of any tutorials that I could use to understand more about the Firebase, or help explain more of the basic concepts that go into implementing a chat feature with it?

Comment: Lots of courses online. I liked this one: https://www.udemy.com/app-idea-swift-with-firebase/ and this https://www.udemy.com/firebases/

Answer (score 3):

How about a no-code answer to a slightly vague question:

You can implement an entire chat app in Firebase. It could be done in Parse but it's not the best solution because it lacks real-time events (other than push notifications).

Data is stored in Firebase 'nodes'. You can think about a node like a slot to hold data (nodes can have sub nodes too). Your firebase app can *observe* any node within your app space.

When something changes in a node your app is *observing*, it is notified of that change and presented data that changed; data being added, changed or removed.

The app can then take action based on that change.

Flow:

```
Your app observes a messages node
A user creates a new message in the messages node
You app is notified of that change and can present the message to another user
```

The documentation on the Firebase site is pretty darn good, with coding examples so I would strongly suggest starting there and read (and re-read) through it until the concept sinks in. Also, try crafting a small app that simply writes data to a node and also observes that node so your app is notified when data changes. A 'Hello, World' example would suffice to get the concept down.